# How to make the items to overflow into columns?

Tags: css

I have a div where I place inside foreach loop some records one by one in a column, like this:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

The problem is that the box where I do that has static height, and those elements go outside of the div, while I want something like this on overflow:

```
aaa ddd
bbb eee
ccc
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please post your code so far?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I guess removing that static height will solve the problem. Try and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `flexbox`, add `align-content: flex-start;` if you need the items to be positioned at the beginning of the container.

Browser support tables, and vendor prefix details [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ojuaehf6/)**

```css
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>aaa</span>
    <span>bbb</span>
    <span>ccc</span>
    <span>ddd</span>
    <span>eee</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set up your div height with:

```
height:auto
```